# iptables rule for limiting bandwidth in given time

Tags: iptables

Under Linux/iptables how can I limit the bandwidth in given time? ex.: don't limit the connection speed from 22h to 06h, but limit it from 06h to 22h, ex.: the max speed would be only 1Mbit/second! How can I do this with iptables?

Comment: you can use squid for this see http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch32_:_Controlling_Web_Access_with_Squid for further reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wondershaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/) based on tc to limit speed. (start and stop it via cron jobs).